# How to format a SharePoint ListItemProperty Date Field

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've got a SharePoint (2010) list with a date field on it.

Now in my custom display form I can go ahead and add the field

```
<SharePoint:ListItemProperty Property="MyDateField" runat="server" id="ListItemProperty1" />
```

which results in the following output

```
21.02.2011 15:44
```

How can I tell SharePoint to format the Date to

```
21.02.2011
```

The only way so far seems to be to create a new calculated column based on that date field and do the formatting within the field definition, but that kind of seems to be the wrong way.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create the "Date" column in the list, there is option to select: 1)Date only ; 2)Date and time. 
If you select the first option, then in the display form, only the date is shown

Comment: Hi GoG, sorry but I don't have that option when creating a new field.

Comment: The option will appear when you select the "Date and Time" type when creating a field.

Comment: @Flo Addition to explication of JamesLove... I think that you have to add completely new column to the list, because I'm not sure if you can edit this option once you create the column. Try creating new column of type "Date", and then select the option "Date only".

Comment: Ok that worked in the end. On a side note: The SP Site has been imported via a wsp file (including the list). The Date fields have already been set to "date only", that's why I was confused in the first place. I havechange the fields back to Date + Time, saved the list and then changed again back to date only -> that worked. Seems to be a bug in SPS.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar task to perform recently, but the client wanted the time stored as well as date, just not to display the date.

The way I got around this was to create a Calculated Column which displayed the date in the format required, and I then just pointed my field control to display that column.

The calculated column had this formula:

```
=TEXT([News Article Date],"dd MMMM yyyy")
```

FYI: this was in a page layout.

Answer (score 0):

Please see http://panvega.wordpress.com/2008/12/08/ddwrtformatdate-with-different-formatflags/ for custom pages.

Answer (score 0):

programmatically (powershell):

```
$web = get-spweb http://thingy/
$list = $web.lists["List Name"]
$datefield = $list.fields["Date Field"]
$datefield.displayformat = [microsoft.sharepoint.spdatetimefieldformattype]::dateonly
$datefield.update()
```